# Why are reaction forces normal to the surface?

Tags: trigonometry, physics, classical-mechanics

I've been studying mechanics for a while now, but I still don't know a very basic point: why is it that when a body is in contact with a plane that the reaction/contact force acts perpendicular to the plane at the point of contact?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Otherwise, it will move spontaneously !!!.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578133/149169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal force is a feature of solids. When two solids come into contact, they resist occupying the same space, interpenetrating each other.

If a force brings two solids towards each other and they are prevented from moving into each other's volume, there must be a force present - a resistance of solids to occupy the same space.

**The normal force is that force which resists an attempt to cause two solids to interpenetrate.**

Hence, the force acts perpendicularly to the surface of contact because a force along the surface of contact would not cause interpenetration, rather that would be involving the frictional force and it's behaviours/rules are different.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because they are defined that way. When a body is in contact with a plane there will be some contact force. This can be split into a component normal to the plane and one parallel to the plane. The component normal to the plane is called *reaction force* and the component parallel to the plane is called *friction force*.

Comment: How can they be components of the same force if the normal reaction force never changes while friction does? Are you saying that there's some sort of force that a body contacting something feels that is constant in one component but the not the other?

Comment: Never changes? The normal reaction force can change. If the plane starts accelerating in the normal direction then the normal reaction force changes.

Comment: What if the object starts accelerating in the direction parallel to the plane; then would the reaction force change?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.

Comment: Then that is my point. When a body is accelerating parallel to the plane how can they be components of the same force if the normal reaction force never changes while friction does? Are you saying that there's some sort of force that a body contacting something feels that is constant in one component but the not the other?

Comment: Yes. The body only sees one force, or rather a lot of small forces in somewhat different directions. The decomposition into a normal reaction force and a parallel friction force is mostly artificial.

Comment: Ok. And the same applies when we're talking about an inclined plane?

Comment: Certainly. A question: How would you define friction force?

Comment: A force that opposes motion (and therefore acts in a direction opposite to motion) and is proportional to the normal reaction force acting on the object in question. Why do you ask?

Comment: So there's no friction on a body in rest on an inclined plane since there's no motion? The reason I ask: How would you separate a parallel component of the reaction force from friction?

Comment: No, on an inclined plane, without friction the body would not be at rest, ie its direction of motion would be downwards, so there is a frictional force present keeping it stationary. Until reading what you have written I have only ever considered the reaction force as a single force acting perpendicular to the surface and friction as being separate from it, so I can't answer your 2nd question.

Comment: But you defined friction as a force that opposes motion. If a body slides freely on a plane, there is motion and so by your definition there is friction. But if a body is stationary, be it on a horizontal or inclined plane, there is no motion, and by your definition there is then no friction.